# Eclipse egit: How to make remote branch local

Tags: eclipse, git, jira, egit

In JIRA, we now have the ability to "create branch" for each issue.  This is lovely, but these branches are only created remotely.  If the developer then switches to this remote branch, he is oddly unable to push anything to it.  This seems to be due to the fact that the branch is not imported into the "local" git repo.

Is there some way to do this?

Note that none of this poses any issue when the branch is created from Eclipse.

No "push" option, for whatever reason:

[image]

git config:

```
[core]
    symlinks = false
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://[username]@bitbucket.org/[project-name]/[project-name].git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

... followed by many other branches, none of which is the one I am trying to use.

Here is what the Branches view shows me in Photon when I attempt to check out a branch:

[image: Note the absence of the ellipsis after the "Check Out" option]

Note the absence of the ellipsis after the "Check Out" option, which means I don't get to choose to "checkout as local branch".

Installing Photon on Ubuntu, I *do* see the ellipsis, and everything works just fine as described.  **Not so much on Windows.**

Of course, Eclipse on Linux has tons of other quirks and bugs, so I won't be using that much.  I'm old enough to remember when people believed in funny abstract ideals like "platform independence".  Sigh...

Comment: You can push anything into a (already-existing) remote branch. If you want to push your current checked out revision (because you didn't create a local branch so working on *detached HEAD*), you can just do it like this with git on cli: `git push whatever-remote HEAD:remote-branch-name`. I'm not saying that this is how I would work (not creating a local branch for a ticket, say.... just saying that it's still possible to push your local work to remote).

Comment: thanks, but I'm really trying to avoid all this command lining.  I kinda hate egit, but it's better than memorizing magical incantations!

Comment: Use the _Branches_ dialog (Ctrl+3 and type `branch`) to check out a remote branch as a local branch with the remote branch configured as the upstream branch. Then you can make your changes, commit and push to the remote upstream branch.

Comment: CTRL-3!  Great tip!  As for the "branches" dialog, that is exactly what I had done before, but doing this results in the branch being checked out (I guess), but without any ability to push code, as described above.

Comment: In fact, the remote branch still has a little black checkmark next to it in this dialog, which I am guessing indicated that it has somehow been checked out before.

Answer (score 4):

make sure you have these settings checked in your configuration. Otherwise there will be no dialog asking what to do with your newly checked out branch:
[image: Settings for GIT-Checkout]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are in the [**detached HEAD state**](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#.22Detached.22_HEAD): the black checked-out mark is not on a local branch because you have checked out a commit or a tag.

If you want to make changes to a remote branch, create a local branch that has the remote branch as the upstream branch first (you cannot make changes directly on the remote branch):

1. **Right-click** the **remote branch**, choose ***Check Out...*** or
    open the Branches dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and type `branch`), select the remote branch and click *Check Out...*)
2. In the following dialog click ***Check Out as New Local Branch*** (not *Check out Commit* which leads to the detached HEAD state)

Comment: but I can't get to step 2, because there is no "following dialog".  I right-click the remote branch in question, or select it in the Branches dialog, and I see the "Checkout" option, but when I select this, the branch is simply checked out in this strange detached head state, and I can do nothing more.

Comment: Which EGit version do you have (I have EGit 5.0)? Or maybe it's a configuration thing: what ref mapping do you have configured for pull and for push?

Comment: I am using Eclipse for JavaScript and Web Developers

Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

but EGit 4.6.1.  Updating fails with "cannot complete the request".... sigh.  Trying harder now.

Comment: After a several failed attempts at upgrading EGit in Neon, I finally gave up and installed Photon.  I now seem to have a "Git integration for Eclipse" plugin 5.0.0.201806131550-r.  OK... I now see "Check Out" (as you indicated, in two words) .... but STILL, no dialog when this option is selected on a remote branch.

Comment: Strange. Can you please share your configuration of the Git repository (especially the ref mapping).

Comment: OK, git config added to the post above.